# Unable to Identify session expiry and Redirect to Session Expired Page

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, servlet-filters, httpsession

I am trying to work on one web application Using Spring boot.
I have been trying to find some solution for Http session handling in a request filter.
I am trying to find out session time out of request and redirect to session expired page.
I have property for session time out set as below

```
server:
session:
    timeout: 180
cookie:
    max-age: 180
```

I would like to explain approach which i have tried till now.
I have written a filter which is request filter as mentioned below

```
public class MonitoringFilter extends GenericFilterBean{
 @Override
 public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
    FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

    if(!request.isRequestedSessionIdValid()){
       //Session has expired
    }
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

I have to somehow put together a condition to differentiate between users first request[When user Logs in From browser] and request from browser after session timeout.

In both scenarios `request.isRequestedSessionIdValid()` will be false and i have also tried using `session.isNew()` which also will not be present because session is null.

```
if(!request.isRequestedSessionIdValid()){
      //Session has expired
}
```

The above condition will be `false` both in case of login request and session timed out request.

I have also tried `request.getRequestedSessionId()` which will be null after session is destroyed.

Please give me some suggestions or any ways to handle this scenario.

Comment: Why do you care? What are you actually trying to achieve? What does "first" mean precisely? first from a given user? from a given browser? first in the last month? in the last year?

Comment: @JBNizet Please check the updated question.
I meant First request from Browser.

Comment: Why do you care? What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: What i am trying to achieve is
1. Wen first login request is received i should  allow the request to pass through the filter.
2. If a request from browser is received after session  time out : Then i have to redirect to error page showing error message that Session has Expired